# Is $\Gamma(x+y+1)\ge\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y+1)$?

Tags: inequality, factorial, gamma-function

I apologize if this has already been asked, but I could not find it. Given $x,y\ge 0$, is it true that $$\Gamma(x+y+1)\ge \Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y+1),$$ where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function? This certainly holds for natural numbers $x,y$, as then $$\Gamma(x+y+1) = (x+y)! \ge x!y! = \Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y+1),$$ and some plots in Mathematica seem to show that this relation also holds true for positive reals, but I have so far been unable to find a proof myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x) = \log \Gamma(x + 1)$ is convex for $x \ge 0$ (compare [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem)) with $f(0) = 0$, and therefore superadditive:
$$
 f(x+y) \ge f(x) + f(y) \, ,
$$
see for example [properties of a convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable).

Comment: True, however, I would need $f(x+y+1)\ge f(x+1) + f(y+1)$. Does this also follow?

Comment: @Analysis801: Sorry, there was an error in the definition of $f$.

Comment: I see, thank you!